# CREATE FUNCTION mysql server version 4.1.7-log

Tags: mysql, function

**SERVER :**

```
    C:\Appserv\mysql\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 14.7 Distrib 4.1.7, for Win95/Win98 (i32)
    
    Connection id:          296 
    Current database: 
    Current user:           ODBC@localhost 
    SSL:                    Not in use 
    Using delimiter:     ; 
    Server version:         4.1.7-log 
    Protocol version:       10 
    Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP 
    Server characterset:    latin1 
    Db     characterset:    latin1 
    Client characterset:    latin1 
    Conn.  characterset:    latin1 
    TCP port:               3306
```

**QUERY FUNCTION :**

```
    CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS isNumeric (input VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS INT  DETERMINISTIC  RETURN input REGEXP '^[0-9]+\\\\.?[0-9]*$';
```

**ERROR LOG :**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS isNumeric (input VARCHAR(255))
```

Comment: Wow.  4.1.7 is almost 20 years old.  Consider it horrifically insecure.  How did you manage to get such an old version?

Answer (score 3):

As mysql manual on [create function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) says (emphasis is mine):

> IF NOT EXISTS prevents an error from occurring if there already exists a routine with the same name. This option is supported with both CREATE FUNCTION and CREATE PROCEDURE beginning with **MySQL 8.0.29**.

Your mysql server version must be older than v8.0.29, this is why you get the syntax error.

Comment: How create function / procedure syntax in mysql v. 4 ?

Comment: @RonaIdea Check if this function exists and create only when the checking result is negative. Or drop the function (DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS, if not supported then drop unconditionally and ignore error) then create it.

Comment: @RonaIdea mysql v4.x does not support stored functions at all. However, you got the version wrong as the version you cited is the mysql cli's version, not mysql server's version. You need to run select version() in cli. Although, you really should replace your cli version.